# Redefine \em to use \slshape

Tags: emphasis, slanted

My google skills are failing me. How do I get `\em` to exhibit it's usual behavior (i.e. `{\em slanted {\em upright} slanted}`), while making the emphasis be that of `\slshape`? If document class has any bearing on it, preferably in `memoir`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just redefine `\em` (defined in `latex.ltx`) to use `\slshape` instead of `\itshape`. Note that this will affect `\emph` also since it uses `\em` internally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\em
  {\@nomath\em \ifdim \fontdimen\@ne\font >\z@
     \eminnershape \else \slshape \fi}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\em slanted {\em upright} slanted}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: I should have just gone to the source! Thanks a bunch!